# https during login on spring application

Tags: spring-security

I'm trying to use https only during login.

The problem is that when the application tries to switch from https to http I end up being redirected to the login form (as if the session is getting destroyed).
when i am using session-fixation-protection="none" after logout when i click on login then it redirect it on login page and then clicking again it logged in.

one more issue after logout click on back button it logged in again which is wrong.

Here is the configuration I'm using:

```
<security:http  auto-config="false" entry-point-ref="authenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint" session-fixation-protection="none">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/login.do*" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS,ROLE_ADMIN_RESEARCHER,ROLE_ADMIN_SUPERVISOR,ROLE_ADMIN_ADMINISTRATOR" requires-channel="https"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/j_spring_security*" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS,ROLE_ADMIN_RESEARCHER,ROLE_ADMIN_SUPERVISOR,ROLE_ADMIN_ADMINISTRATOR" requires-channel="https"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/assets/**" filters="none"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/change_password.do/*" filters="none"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/forgot_password.do*" filters="none"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/upload_tracking.do**" access="ROLE_ADMIN_SUPERVISOR"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/company_alias.do*" access="ROLE_ADMIN_ADMINISTRATOR" requires-channel="http"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/contacts.do*" access="ROLE_ADMIN_ADMINISTRATOR" requires-channel="http"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/technology.do*" access="ROLE_ADMIN_ADMINISTRATOR" requires-channel="http"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/technologyProduct.do*" access="ROLE_ADMIN_ADMINISTRATOR" requires-channel="http"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/technologyKeyword.do*" access="ROLE_ADMIN_ADMINISTRATOR" requires-channel="http"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/services.do*" access="ROLE_ADMIN_ADMINISTRATOR" requires-channel="http"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/services.do*" access="ROLE_ADMIN_ADMINISTRATOR" requires-channel="http"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/subscriptions.do*" access="ROLE_ADMIN_ADMINISTRATOR" requires-channel="http"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/reports.do*" access="ROLE_ADMIN_ADMINISTRATOR" requires-channel="http"/>      
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/goCsvUpload" access="ROLE_ADMIN_ADMINISTRATOR" requires-channel="http"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin_user.do*" access="ROLE_ADMIN_ADMINISTRATOR" requires-channel="http"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN_RESEARCHER,ROLE_ADMIN_SUPERVISOR,ROLE_ADMIN_ADMINISTRATOR" requires-channel="http"/>

    <security:form-login login-page="/login.do" default-target-url="/home.do"
                         login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check.do"
                         always-use-default-target="false"
                         authentication-failure-url="/login.do?login_error=1"/>
    <security:anonymous/>

    <!-- remember-me default is two weeks, alter attribute token-validity-seconds if needed -->
    <security:remember-me/>
    <security:logout logout-url="/logout.do" logout-success-url="/login.do?logout=ok"/>

</security:http>


<security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
    <security:password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder">
        <!-- Very important! id is used as salt also by the registration process -->
        <!-- Cannot use username because it might contain braces, forbidden by the std salt generator -->
        <security:salt-source user-property="id"/>
    </security:password-encoder>
</security:authentication-provider>

<bean id="passwordEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.providers.encoding.ShaPasswordEncoder"/>

<bean id="passwordGenerator" class="com.salebuild.util.PasswordGenerator"/>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.salebuild.security">
    <context:include-filter type="annotation"
                            expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Service"/>
</context:component-scan>

<security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled"/>

<bean class="java.lang.Boolean" id="customerAuthentication">
    <constructor-arg value="false"/>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven/>
```

Comment: i got a solution regarding this..